# Why does assignment operator not work as expected?

Tags: c++, c++11, assignment-operator

**UPD:** I can see now how stupid this question is, it's just my misunderstanding of C++ constructions.

I got stuck with operator assignment problem - it doesn't work as expected. Here's the example code:

```
#include <iostream>

class TestClass{
private:
    int pop;
public:
    TestClass(){
        std::cout<<"Default Constuctor\n";
    }
    TestClass(int i):pop(i){
        std::cout<<"Param Constuctor\n";
    }

    TestClass &operator=(const TestClass &other){
        std::cout<<"Assignment Operator \n";
        return *this;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, TestClass &x);
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, TestClass &x){
    out<<" This is the TestClass with pop=" << x.pop <<"\n";
    return out;
}


int main()
{
    TestClass    P0(333);
    TestClass P_foo(555);

    P_foo = P0;

    std::cout << P0;
    std::cout << P_foo;

    return 0;
}
```

The result of this program is

```
Param Constuctor
Param Constuctor
Assignment Operator 
 This is the TestClass with pop=333
 This is the TestClass with pop=555
```

So `P_foo` object preserves the initialized value 555.
If I comment out my custom assignment operator, the program works as expected.

```
Param Constuctor
Param Constuctor
 This is the TestClass with pop=333
 This is the TestClass with pop=333
```

What's wrong with my assignment operator function?

Comment: Your assignment operator function doesn't assign anything. So, it doesn't assign anything. It does what you told it to: it prints a message and doesn't assign anything. Are you still confused about why it doesn't assign anything?

Comment: Add in the assignment operator function something to do the assignment.

Comment: maybe you misunderstood that you have to declare the assignment operator and then the compiler will add some magic. It is rather the opposite, if you do not declare the assignment operator the compiler does it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see several issues with this code:

- `pop` is not being initialized in the default constructor (which you are not calling, but you should still implement it properly, if you are going to implement it manually at all).
- `operator=` is not updating the value of `this->pop` at all, which is the root cause of your issue.  If you declare `operator=`, you are responsible for implementing it properly yourself, the compiler will not help you at all.  But if you do not declare `operator=`, the compiler will auto-generate a default implementation that will assign a copy of the `pop` value for you.
- `operator<<` should be taking the `TestClass` parameter by *const* reference.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class TestClass{
private:
    int pop;
public:
    TestClass() : pop(0) { // <-- add this value!
        std::cout << "Default Constructor\n";
    }

    TestClass(int i) : pop(i) {
        std::cout << "Param Constructor\n";
    }

    TestClass& operator=(const TestClass &other){
        std::cout << "Assignment Operator\n";
        pop = other.pop; // <-- add this!
        return *this;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const TestClass &x);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const TestClass &x){
    out << " This is the TestClass with pop=" << x.pop << "\n";
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    TestClass    P0(333);
    TestClass P_foo(555);

    P_foo = P0; // <-- this will work as expected now

    std::cout << P0;
    std::cout << P_foo;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> What's wrong with my assignment operator function?

At no point does `*this` get modified in your implementation of `operator=`:

```
    TestClass &operator=(const TestClass &other){
        std::cout<<"Assignment Operator \n";
        return *this;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TestClass &operator=(const TestClass &other){
    std::cout << "Assignment Operator \n";
    pop = other.pop;    // You need to add this
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the assignment operator you defined doesn't assign anything to the instance it is called on.

Read through your operator again:

```cpp
TestClass &operator=(const TestClass &other){
    std::cout<<"Assignment Operator \n";
    return *this;
}
```

You can see that two things happen. `Assignment Operator` is printed, and `*this` is returned. But your "other" TestClass is not used at all, and the data in `this` is never modified.

You can fix that by assigning to `this->pop` like so:

```cpp
TestClass &operator=(const TestClass &other){
    std::cout<<"Assignment Operator \n";
    pop = other.pop; // Now this->pop will be assigned a new value from other.pop
    return *this;
}
```

Now when you assign `P_foo = P0`, `P_foo` is successfully assigned the pop value from `P0`.